# Sliding menu from the top hides behind Safari mobile bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a serious issue with my dropdown settings on iOS Safari. Imagine a website, which has a header on the top. If you click the header, it will slide down, just like any notification center on mobile phones. The way I chose was quite simple. I have a `<div class="settings hide">` with this css:

```
.settings{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh + 60px);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 10;
}

.hide{
    top: -100vh;
}
```

Now, this makes it look like so:

[image: figure-one(the hidden setting)]

Now, the next step was to create it "slide-able" which I've done using jQuery, by adding class called "show".

```
.show{
    top: calc(0vh - 60px);
}
```

And this actually made it great. It just worked! Suddenly I tried the website on my iPhone, and because of the bottom bar, always showing until you scroll, my hipe was all gone.

Because it look like this:

[image: Figure-two(it is hidden behind the bar!)]

Getting it so far? My menu did slide correctly, looks great in any browser, but here in Safari, it is hidden right behind the bar, so user actually can't close it.

I tried my best to solve this issue, butnothing really worked as I wanted.

PS: I assume you know that, but it kinda works when you use `bottom: 0;`, then it "knows" about the bar and stops correctly right above it. But because the setting is calculated with `top` position, it `does not` do the animation, which is necessary for my design.

Any help/solution appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David, unfortunately iOS Safari is full of unpleasant surprises.

One of them is what iOS Safari considers `100vh`.
**Viewport height** in iOS Safari is not equal **window inner height** as in Chrome or Firefox.

E.g. on iPhone 7plus `100vh == 696px`, but `window.innerHeight == 628px`.
On iPhone 6 `100vh == 628px`, but `window.innerHeight == 559px`.
And so on...

So the solution is getting rid of `100vh`.
Assuming that `body` is offset parent of `.settings` use `100%` instead:

```
.settings {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% + 60px);
    ...
}

.hide {
    top: -100%;
}
```

Also you do not need to use `calc` in your `.show` class (since 0vh === 0):

```
.show {
    top: -60px;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Very Well writen response. I will try it tomorrow and See If it works for me. Thanks for now!

Comment: No problem! I faced this problem last summer, 'twas awful. Safari is new IE J.