# Calculating browsers navigator on mobile

Tags: javascript, css

I have 3 important div's on my page. 2 of them has a fixed height and 1 should fit the window height. I use `calc(100vh - 260px);` on CSS and it works completely fine on Chrome's "device toolbar". However, when I try it on my phone with Chrome, the browser doesn't extract the browsers navigation bar height from the 100vh and bottom of the third element goes under viewport. Is there a way to fix this via CSS or Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already answered the very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979694/sliding-menu-from-the-top-hides-behind-safari-mobile-bar/44980623#44980623).

Long story short, use `100%` instead of `100vh`.

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear. I have other elements under the 3 important elements that I want to show. So making 100% won't work for me :/.

Comment: You probably do not understand how to use it. Could you please add a code snippet (jsfiddle or codepen or whatever) to your question?

Comment: Oh thanks i did it by your way. I just made the parent's height calc(100% - 260px) and childs height 50% and it worked. Thanks!